# What do you call the expression inside brackets?

Tags: reference-request, terminology

Suppose I have

$$x\bigg(\frac{abcd^{n-141+xy}}{fds^{3C}}+dfd+1+... etc.\bigg)$$

In order to not have repeat the cumbersome expression within the brackets, I was wondering if there was some useful term for reference, just like how one might refer the the RHS, or LHS etc. Would the 'interior expression' make it clear what I mean?

Comment: In this particular case, you could say *the fraction*.

Comment: And in general? This was just a special example.

Comment: Sorry. I thought you hinted at the fact that I should update my question and clarify exactly what I'm after.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Quite right, I was about to say that there was more than one term within the parentheses...

Comment: $$ x\bigg(\underbrace{\frac{abcd^{n-141+xy}}{fds^{3C}}+dfd+1+... etc.}_{=:\text{just give it some name}}\bigg) $$

Comment: I'd rather hear "the terms within the brackets" than "interior expression", the latter sounds like it could be some kind of advanced terminology.

Comment: "the second/last/complicated factor"

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think the purpose of comments is to help to make the question more clear and not to "freeze" the question. If a comment becomes obsolete you can remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call it whatever you want, it's kind of the beauty of Maths. 
Yes, the "interior expression works" but the moment you operate or rearrange, you may have a new interrior expression and this may cause confusion.  Your safest bet is to just "$Let$" it be anything. For example:
$Let$ $A=\bigg(\frac{abcd^{n-141+xy}}{fds^{3C}}+dfd+1+... etc.\bigg)$

Then for the rest of your work, unless you redefine $A$, you won't have to rewrite the long expression.